# How can access to subjects of an array from console

Tags: php, arrays, json, console.log

I Can print Object/Arrays from php into Console and than access its sub objects.

For example I've some array in php

```
<?php 
    $arr = Array('name'=>'sajjad','age'=>'20','sex'=>'m');
    $json = json_encode($arr);
?>
<script>
    console.log(<?php echo $json; ?>);
</script>
```

I will get following lines as object in chrome console.log.

> Object {name: "sajjad", age: "20", sex: "m"}

Suppose i'm not working on backend, how can i access to the subobjects of this  object in chrome console panel. like..

For example if I type

```
>object.name

( and hit enter , console should return me)
>sajjad
```

or If I type in console

```
   >object.age
   >20
```

or

```
   >object.sex
   >m
```

Thanks
... For understanding. please see pic one. what i want.
[image]

Comment: update: suppose I'm not working in backend. I want to type within console "obejct.name" to get result in console. I'm not working on backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. I searched but couldn't find. But a little hit and try helped.

**Problem:**

[image]

**Solution**
1.

[image]

2.

[image]

3.

[image]

I hope somebody else do need this solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just assign that json encoded array into script variable and console log object elements using index, like below:

```
<?php 
$arr = Array('name'=>'sajjad','age'=>'20','sex'=>'m');
$json = json_encode($arr);
?>
<script>
var obj = <?php echo $json; ?>;
console.log(obj.name); ///sajjad
console.log(obj.age); ///20
console.log(obj.sex); ///m
</script>
```

Comment: this was a sample array.. the actual array contains more than 200 rows, with nothing repeated row. a dozens of sub objects etc. I know the above you mentioned method and I can even find and process in other way. but my target is to get results in console from console.

Comment: @MFarooqi you can get sub array simply like this `obj.subarray1.name` this will give you the name in sub node of object .. can u please provide more information about your array and what actually you want then it will be helpful

Comment: I've found the solution I was looking for. Actually after some hit and trial.. i get the solution. should I answer my self?

Comment: yeah you can edit your question and add the solution for this problem and also close the question ..